# Form posting other page getting error with php

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

Problem with form posting to other page (redirection) and db storage and getting results I am beginner in php

Here is the code

```
include 'include/header.php';
include 'include/connect.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && $_SESSION['id']!='')

    $reslt = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `queries` WHERE   id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
    $row1= mysqli_fetch_array($reslt);


    if(isset($_POST['submitquery'])){
        $title= $_POST['title'];
        $contact = $_POST['queries'];

        header("Location:pnf.php");
    }else{
        $msg='<span style="color:red;text-align:center;font-size:15px">Sorry you miss some</span>';   
    }
```

html

```
<form method="post" class="postquations">
    <label><b><class="p">Set your quaition title</b></label>
    <br>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Title"id="title" name="title"  minlength="25" required=""autocomplete="off"  oninvalid="true"><br>
    <label><b>ask your quation</b></label>
    <br>

    <textarea class="textinput" rows="10" minlength="100" id="queries"name="queries" style="overflow:hidden" placeholder="Comment Here.." required></textarea>
    <input type="submit"id="submit" class="butn"value="POST" name="submitquery">
</form>
```

pnf.php

```
<div class="title" > <?php echo $row['title'];?></div>
<div class="quation"> <?php echo $row['queries'];?></div>
```

please help me and explain why we are not getting results Thanks in advance

Comment: what are u expecting on `pnf.php`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile result page

Comment: I dont see a `session_start()` is there one in one of the include files?

Comment: also I dont see `$row`

Comment: Your `<form method="post" class="postquations">` does not have an `action="nameOfPHPScript.php` attribute

Comment: what results are u expecting on `pnf.php`?

Comment: yes we have header location

Comment: See where you are checking the session I think the braces are missing

Comment: can anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

`header("Location:pnf.php");` causes php to set a location header in the response,
the users browser will read this header and perform a new GET request to `pnf.php`.

As this is a new GET request, `$_POST` will not be populated when `pnf.php` is ran.

Also, the whole sql code appears to redundant.

The whole thing could probably do with a rethink, but the simplest option would be to change the forms `action` attribute to `pnf.php` and process the data there

Comment: If you have specific questions i am happy to answer them, but i wont attempt to 'give solved code' because I dont know anywhere near enough about your project to do so, and you wouldnt learn much anyway if i did.